# How can I submit my textbox value to go to a a link in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a video conference, what I need is to join the room by entering a link to the textbox.

Right now, I have able to get the textbox value but the problem is I cannot go to another link. Can anyone help me with this?

```
function Home(){
    const [data,setData] = useState(null)
    const [print, setPrint] = useState(false);

    function getData(val){
        setData(val.target.value)
        setPrint(false)
    }

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <h3>Welcome, Instructor</h3>
            <hr />
            {
                print?
                <h1>{data}</h1>
                :null
            }
            {/* Link supposed to be here */}
            <TextField label="Room ID" onChange={getData} />
            <hr/>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setPrint(true)}>JOIN ROOM</Button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) in `react-router-dom`

```
<Link to={`/${data}`}>Join</Link>
<TextField label="Room ID" onChange={getData} />
```

Comment: any advice how can i learn advanced in react?

Answer (score 0):

What you specifically need, is using the textbox information, you want to generate dynamic links.

In such a case, we can be certain that, we need to use the dynamic information to create the link, which can be achieved either by concatenation

```js
const name = "Mike";
console.log("Hello" + name); // Hello Mike
```

or you can use string interpolation / templating

```js
const name = "Mike";
console.log(`Hello` ${name}`); // Hello Mike
```

Both of these are Javascript features and have nothing to do with React specifically.

The React specific information here is, whenever variables inside JSX part of components change, re-renders are caused and thus links will be updated.

So, anything like `` <a href=`https://example.com/some/random/${stateVariable}/chat` /> ``